# Bad gateway error when navigating to localhost:8000 on travis for protractor e2e testing

Tags: protractor, travis-ci, saucelabs

I am trying to set up continuous integration on Travis for my web app. I would like to unit test & end to end test in different browsers using sauce-labs. I have poured over documentation for the last few days, and am still stuck on getting both the e2e and unit tests to execute on the travis server (sequentially, not in parallel).

.travis.yml

```
addons:
  sauce_connect: true

branches:
  only:
  - master
  - passing_test_branch

sudo: required

services:
- redis-server

language: node_js
node_js:
- 0.10.36

before_install:
- export PIP_USE_MIRRORS=true

install:
- npm install
- sudo -H pip install -r requirements.txt
- bower install

script:
- grunt karma:sauceTravis
- grunt protractor:sauceLabs
- coverage run --source='.' manage.py test

after_success:
- grunt coveralls:run
- coveralls --merge=coverage/lcov/coveralls.json
```

protractor-sauce.conf.js

// conf.js

```
exports.config = {

  // seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4443/wd/hub',

  sauceUser: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
  sauceKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,

  multiCapabilities: [
      {
        'name': 'Protractor Tests - Travis',
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'version': '35',
        'platform': 'Windows 7',
        'tunnel-identifier': process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER,
        'build': process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER,
      }, 
      {
        'name': 'Protractor Tests - Travis',
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'version': '41',
        'platform': 'Windows 7',
        'tunnel-identifier': process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER,
        'build': process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER,
      }, 
      {
        'name': 'Protractor Tests - Travis',
        'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        'version': '11',
        'platform': 'Windows 7',
        'tunnel-identifier': process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER,
        'build': process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER,
      },
      {
        'name': 'Protractor Tests - Travis',
        'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        'version': '10',
        'platform': 'Windows 7',
        'tunnel-identifier': process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER,
        'build': process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER,
      },
      {
        'name': 'Protractor Tests - Travis',
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'version': '40',
        'platform': 'Windows 7',
        'tunnel-identifier': process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER,
        'build': process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER,
      }, 
  ],

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  specs: ['./test/e2e/*.js'],

  jasmineNodeOpts: {

    showColors: true,

  },

  params: {

    TEST_PASS: process.env.TEST_PASS,

  }
};
```

gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var customLaunchers = {
        sl_chrome: {
            base: 'SauceLabs',
            browserName: 'chrome',
            platform: 'Windows 7',
        },
        sl_firefox: {
            base: 'SauceLabs',
            browserName: 'firefox',
            platform: 'Windows 7',
        },
        sl_ios_safari: {
            base: 'SauceLabs',
            browserName: 'safari',
            platform: 'OS X 10.9',
        },
        sl_ie_11: {
            base: 'SauceLabs',
            browserName: 'internet explorer',
            platform: 'Windows 7',
        }
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        karma: {
            options: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
            },
            unit: {

            },
            test: {

                singleRun: true,
                browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

            },

            sauceLocal: {

                sauceLabs: {

                    testName: 'Karma Tests - LOCAL',
                    startConnect: true

                },

                customLaunchers: customLaunchers,
                browsers: Object.keys(customLaunchers),
                reporters: ['progress','coverage','saucelabs'],

                singleRun: true,
                recordScreenshots: false,
                autoWatch: false,

                browserNoActivityTimeout: 150000,

            },

            sauceTravis: {

                coverageReporter: {
                    dir: 'coverage',
                    reporters: [
                        { type: 'lcovonly', subdir: 'lcov' },
                    ]
                },

                sauceLabs: {
                    testName: 'Karma Tests - TRAVIS',

                    startConnect: false,
                    tunnelIdentifier: process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER,
                    build: 'TRAVIS #' + process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER + ' ; BUILD ID #' + process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_ID,
                },

                customLaunchers: customLaunchers,
                browsers: Object.keys(customLaunchers),
                reporters: ['progress','coverage','saucelabs'],

                singleRun: true,
                recordScreenshots: false,
                autoWatch: false,

                browserNoActivityTimeout: 150000,
                keepAlive: false
            },

            lcov: {

                singleRun: true,

                browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

                coverageReporter: {
                    dir: 'coverage',
                    reporters: [
                        { type: 'lcovonly', subdir: 'lcov' },
                    ]
                },

            },
        },

        protractor: {
            options: {

                keepAlive: false,
                singleRun: true, 

            },
            test: {   // Grunt requires at least one target to run so you can simply put 'all: {}' here too.

                configFile: "protractor.conf.js", // Default config file

            },

            sauceLabs: {

                configFile: "protractor-sauce.conf.js",

            },
        },

        coveralls: {
            options: {

                coverageDir: 'coverage/lcov',
                dryRun: true,

            },
            run: {

            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma-coveralls');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['karma:unit']);
    grunt.registerTask('e2e', ['protractor:test']);
    grunt.registerTask('fullTest', ['karma:sauceTravis', 'protractor:sauceLabs']);
    grunt.registerTask('karmaSauce', ['karma:sauceLocal']);

};
```

You can see in my travis.yml that I am using the sauce_connect addon, which launches a sauce connect instance while building my travis server. My script involves launching the grunt task "karma:sauceLabs", which executes fine through the sauce connect tunnel (i can see the results in sauce), however when I try to run the protractor e2e tests on travis, I get the following errors, and when I check on sauceLabs I get a "badgateway" error when I attempt to connect to localhost:8000.

```
The command "grunt karma:sauceTravis" exited with 0.
40.64s$ grunt protractor:sauceLabs
Running "protractor:sauceLabs" (protractor) task
[launcher] Running 5 instances of WebDriver
FFFFFFF
------------------------------------
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] PID: 4694
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] Specs: /home/travis/build//cv/test/e2e/login.spec.js
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] 
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] Using SauceLabs selenium server at http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] FF
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] 
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] Failures:
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] 
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   1) Login should not allow for login with an invalid username and password
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]    Message:
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]      NoSuchElementError: no such element
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.93)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d5321e),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]    Stacktrace:
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]      NoSuchElementError: no such element
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.93)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d5321e),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at Array.forEach (native)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/travis/build//cv/test/e2e/login.spec.js:12:51)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] Error
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/travis/build//cv/test/e2e/login.spec.js:8:5)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build//cv/test/e2e/login.spec.js:2:1)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at require (module.js:380:17)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at Function.promise (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:650:9)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at _fulfilled (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at /home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at flush (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] 
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   2) Login should allow for login with a valid username and password
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]    Message:
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]      NoSuchElementError: no such element
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.93)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d5321e),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]    Stacktrace:
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]      NoSuchElementError: no such element
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.93)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d5321e),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at Array.forEach (native)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/travis/build//cv/test/e2e/login.spec.js:23:51)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] Error
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/travis/build//cv/test/e2e/login.spec.js:19:5)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build//cv/test/e2e/login.spec.js:2:1)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at require (module.js:380:17)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at Function.promise (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:650:9)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at _fulfilled (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at /home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at flush (/home/travis/build//cv/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5]     at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] 
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] Finished in 22.342 seconds
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] 2 tests, 2 assertions, 2 failures
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] 
[chrome 40 Windows 7 #5] SauceLabs results available at http://saucelabs.com/jobs/a94dc37936734d188eb2e60abf3f8d65
```

So I guess my issue is that the sauce tunnel is open appropriately, I can see that my browsers are reaching sauceLabs, but when I attempt to navigate to localhost:8000 in saucelabs I get a "bad gateway" error instead of my website. Any advice on what I can do in my config to get rid of the bad gateway error

Thanks

Comment: So i figured out why I was getting a bad gateway error...I am pointing at localhos:8000 for my protractor tests, but I never spun up a localhost:8000 server.

Comment: It was working sometimes, because I had a separate sauceConnect instance spun up from my console. Basically I just need to spin up the local host on my travis server and it should be fine.